# PayPay Billing address and Shipping address

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I am facing a strange issue with PayPal express checkout. This is the first time i noticed it.

When a customer enters a separate billing and shipping addresses and goes to PayPal checkout page, On PayPal checkout page instead of showing different billing and shipping address its showing same address ie: Shipping address for both billing and shipping address field.

[image: Here the address displayed was inserted as a shipping address billing address was different]

Answer (score 1):

Hope following code will help for you:

Find `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Standard.php` file and go to line number 134 (According to Magento CE 1.8)

```
Replace following code 

$address = $isOrderVirtual ? $order->getBillingAddress() : $order->getShippingAddress();
if ($isOrderVirtual) {
    $api->setNoShipping(true);
} elseif ($address->validate()) {
    $api->setAddress($address);
}

with 

$address =$order->getBillingAddress();
if ($address->validate()) {
    $api->setAddress($address);
}
```

Comment: This is not working with Magento 1.8. I am using express checkout i also tried the same tweak in Express.php but didn't worked.